# How to unlink mesh from an empty?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, transforms

I have a mesh I downloaded that had a couple empties attached to it and I dont really like it being there. How would I remove the empty but keep the positioning and scale of the mesh its linked to? 
[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your object and press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *(Clear Parent)* > *Clear And Keep Transformation*